# How to send enter key when ever dialogue box is appears

Tags: autohotkey

I am new in autohotkey, How to send enter key when ever dialogue box is appears the title of the dialogue box is "conversion" sometimes times this dialog box may appears more than once. Is it possible ?

Comment: See https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples

Comment: sorry to be rude, but why did this get upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the AU3_Spy.exe from your Autohotkey folder to find the correct title for that window.
Then use this:

```
SetTimer, CloseDialogue
CloseDialogue:
    WinWait, title
    WinClose, title
Return
```

and replace title with the correct title of your window.

[WinClose](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm)
[WinWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm)